# LinearLayout animate() clips the view, clipChildren doesn't work

Tags: android, animation, android-linearlayout

I'm trying to animate the `container` LinearLayout (20dp) and `btn` button (20dp) (moving them right), but they get clipped after the full width of the `main` LinearLayout (40dp). I have tried `clipChildren="false"` on both, but it doesn't work. I can't use `match_parent` sizes for layouts, because it is an overlay app and will block the touches behind.

Any ideas?

My layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:clipToPadding="false" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:clipChildren="false"
        android:clipToPadding="false" >        
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn" />

</LinearLayout>
```

My (simplified) code:

```
super.onCreate();       
windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, //can't have MATCH_PARENT
    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, //can't have MATCH_PARENT
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT | 
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL |
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
    PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
main = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.main,null);

btn = (ImageButton)main.findViewById(R.id.btn);
container = (LinearLayout)main.findViewById(R.id.container);
btn.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);        
windowManager.addView(main, params);
}
```

Animation code:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
btn.animate().xBy(100f).setDuration(2000);
container.animate().xBy(100f).setDuration(2000);
}
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I have a similar issue, android:clipChildren works but as soon as you apply padding to a view, it gets clipped, even if setClipToPadding is set to false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you cannot draw outside the bounds of the initial area that was added to the screen using `windowManager.addView`.

In my case to animate the views I had to use `windowManager.updateViewLayout(view,layoutParams)`.